# We need to warn "people you'll work with" that their pics, names, and location are used on public ads

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs, advertising

I've been noticing this much more recently.  We are running advertisements with people's profile pics for the job ads, like this one:

[image]

The other day I saw someone I knew on here in one of these ads.  When I spoke to him I congratulated him for being on the front page of SO.  He was shocked, the "heck you talking about"...well the ads have your picture on it...

And although the picture is a public profile picture I don't think people realize that it will hit the front pages for everyone to see.  The picture also has your full name on it...hence people (including my buddy) freaked out.  He then wanted to go and edit his profile information and picture as to avoid this.

I am not against capturing this data - besides we need it when you apply for a job...but I think we need to be careful by at least alerting candidates that their picture and name can be used in an SO advertisement.  *I certainly think it's the nice thing to do.*

Warn them or cut the crap about who you're going to "work with..." directly on the advertisement.  I don't think that is appropriate at all.  Besides who in their right mind starts working at a job just because someone else they know (more times then not they DONT KNOW) works there?  When I look for a job I don't pay attention to who works there but I pay attention to mgmt styles, salary, health insurance, family friendly, etc. not who works there.

Currently I have the name, the picture, and the company someone works for...Wow with that amount of information I can practically find where this person is (where they live, a phone number, their route to work).  It's too much info for little return on investment.

**Please remove the "who you'll work with" specifically on advertisements.**

Here's a sample of the invite:

[image]

This email has nothing addressing the fact that my information, location, and picture may be used in an advertisement promoting the company I work for.

**Allow easy opt out (for the actual candidates):**

We should also as users be able to OPT-OUT of this and this should not be a process where I need to email SO or talk to my "company admin".  As it stands company admins are the only ones who can remove a person from the list of "people you'll work with".

Comment: How is this any different than having your question (and avatar) on the front page in the question list?

Comment: Attaching your profile to a careers company is *opt in*. Companies can't just add these without consent.

Comment: Oded I am just giving you feedback.  You may have hundreds of thousands of people who post and answer questions - but you have millions upon millions of lurkers.  This could freak people out.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I may opt into looking for a job - but that doesnt give my consent to anyone to use my name and picture for an advertisement to a company I work at...that doesnt make any sense.  Just so you know I actually agree with my buddy on this topic.  I find it odd that we even show this for ads..why is it important.  Most of the time people dont even KNOW these other people.

Comment: @Oded - You're not representing your company just by posting a question/answer on Stack Overflow. The image I use for Facebook is not the same one I use on my company's Chatter (basically Facebook for companies).

Comment: @JonH: I'm just providing context. I am not currently attached to my employers career page, so I won't be shown. I can't test what the opt-in UI looks like at this point, because the company would have to invite me to connect my profile. I suspect that *that opt-in page* has some wording as to what I am opting into. I just know that I have been connected to such a page (and the job adverts) in the past, with my full consent.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I've been on both sides of this since I have used it as a hiring manager.  There is no wording as to your face, name, and your job will be plastered on an advertisement.  Get rid of it - it is completely wrong on all levels.

Comment: @JonH: so your buddy *at some point* made a choice to connect their profile to the company page. They were invited to do so. There *may* be an issue with how clear the consequences are when you do this, but this was not something they walked into without at least opting in first.

Comment: @JonH: Your buddy can opt out again too, I'm sure.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Not just my buddy, everyone.  I think the benefits are zilch here, please let me know if that is something you look at to find a job?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I don't think this is so easy to simply opt-out.  I just don't think that "people you'll work with" is in fact something we want to keep.  It has a bad vibe to it.

Comment: @JonH: "the benefits are zilch here"? If I respect certain community members for their answers, and I found out that I could work with them, then that might be a factor, absolutely! And please don't speak for 'everyone', people need to be able to make this choice for themselves. Again, I don't know what the opt-in UI looks like, but *that is possibly the only issue here, that people are informed properly as to what opting in **means***. Nothing more.

Comment: @JonH: I'm sorry you feel this has a 'bad vibe' to it. If my employer felt I would be a great asset to advertise with, I'd certainly entertain the thought of consenting.

Comment: @JonH: from an earlier comment I have the impression that you think the consent is given when you *apply for a job*. That is **not** what I am talking about. A company that has a careers account to advertise job openings with, can create a page showing off the company and invite people with accounts on Stack Overflow to connect that account to the page and the job advertisements. That is *entirely separate from the application process*.

Comment: The UI is not good at all as to what this does to the candidate.  It simply asks an "Admin" of a company page to invite users to join their company.  It does not detail or give any wording on how this suddenly becomes an advertisement bearing their information.  Sorry you may want to sell yourself or be the face of your company - I can counter that with many more don't want to opt - in to such a thing.  And even if they have the opportunity to opt out (btw they do not - only the admin of the company page can change this) its rather tedious for anyone to be surprised like a REAL client was!

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I already understand that as I have used it for both finding candidates and being a candidate I fully understand the UI in that sense.

Comment: @JonH: your earlier comment seems to attach the two: *I may opt into looking for a job - but that doesnt give my consent to anyone to use my name and picture for an advertisement to a company I work at*. Looking for a job doesn't opt you into attaching yourself to a company page.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - But neither does the fact that a company admin sending me an invite without me knowing any of this.  If I am invited to a company page that doesn't tell me I could possibly be giving my name, face, and location in an advertisement publicly for all to see.  We agree to disagree...Sorry I don't think most not just me most people care about who you'll work with.

Comment: @JonH: You misunderstand me then. Because *if the user is not informed when they opt in* then that *is* an issue. Users invited to attach their account to such a page should be able to determine what they consent to, and should be able to opt out. I'm just not assuming that everyone will be upset with the use of their profile in job adverts.

Comment: @JonH: so I suggest the next steps are to a) determine how much information a user is given when invited, and b) if they can opt out again later on, then c) update your post to address those issues. As it stands, the post is making too many assumptions about how people feel about this use.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - It is linked as a picture at the bottom of this post.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134704/discussion-on-question-by-jonh-we-need-to-warn-people-youll-work-with-that-th).

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I disagree - I think the post gives you or anyone else enough information about how to proceed.  The fact is there isn't much more I can give you if the UI does NOT address it.  Again I am not going to argue with you Martijn

Comment: *Besides who in their right mind starts working at a job just because someone else they know...works there?* - To be fair, I think you just described networking.

Comment: @BSMP - But it's not the prime factor so I think having it on an ad defeats that purpose.

Comment: Please move this conversation into chat. There are _way_ too many comments here already.

Comment: @rossipedia - rightfully so...this is an important topic that some people are not aware of.

Comment: @JonH Maybe you don't care about who your co-workers are and what they're like, but for me it's a critical factor when deciding where I work.  I'm going to be spending a huge part of my day working with these people for a long time, and my quality of life will be directly related to how well they can both do their job and work effectively with me.  Saying that nobody cares at all about their (potential) co-workers in any way is simply wrong.   You *personally* might not care.

Comment: Servy we've established that

Comment: I'm sympathetic to making it more clear that being part of a company page _could_ end up in advertising for that company if the company decides to pay for such advertising. Your claims that people don't care about seeing people in the ads is anecdotal and not supported by data in the four years we've been running these ads.

Comment: Bret - How exactly are you capturing data that lends me to believe this is actually making a difference?  We've established that some people find this helpful - but let's not forget the real question here...there is no reason to have this in the ad.  And if there is you better get my or anyone else's consent.  You also need to ensure people can Opt out, which they can presently not opt out of...

Comment: @Oded: Avatars don't show up on the front page question list.

Comment: Bret what you stated is incorrect. Four years ago these ads never existed. And even if they did you guys never had a who youll be working for directly on the ad. Any data you plan on presenting cannot be trusted nor is it relevant one bit because this type of data does not give you the full picture of whether people really care about working at a place because they saw the "who works there". This is nonsense.

Comment: @JonH You might want to @-reply to Bret if you want him to actually notice/respond to your comments. He might check back on the post without that, sure, but you know how pings work.

Comment: @Oded wow, really? Most of the questions I asked were not related to the company I worked for at all. Why would you asume that all questions on the front page are there because a developer is struggling with a certain code issue at work? Beside that, a developer explicitly click the button 'post question' an therefor knows that he is publishing his question on the public internet.

Answer (score 56):

In regards to the title of your question:

> We need to warn “people you'll work with” that their pics, names, and location are used on public ads

You're absolutely right. We need to be more clear about that. As you noted, participation in a company page is currently explicitly *opt-in*, but that copy (the email invitation) needs to be much more clear that your avatar *could* appear in Company Page Ads for the company you are joining.

A Company Page on Stack Overflow *is* promotional content for that company. There is currently no other reason to opt-in to displaying your profile on a Company Page other than to advertise that you work for that company.

But yeah, we *do* need to be much more explicit about that in the invitation email, and that is currently being fixed.

And, for what it's worth, this is the first time in 4 years (that I can recall) that we've had any complaints or issues about it. Not that it absolves us of responsibility at all, I'm just pointing that out.

---

Also, you can revoke your membership to any company page that you have joined from your Developer Story preferences (it's under Edit Profile and Settings). You don't need the owner's permission:

[image]

For some perspective in regards to your statement:

> I congratulated him for being on the front page of SO. He was shocked, the "heck you talking about"...well the ads have your picture on it...

Here are some numbers during our highest traffic periods:

- ~300 running company page ad campaigns, as of last count.
- 375 total ad impressions per second
- 50 peak company page ads served per second

So for a given home page view, you're looking at 1/7.5 chance of seeing a CP ad. And if you do, it's a further 1/300 chance of seeing the ad for the specific Company Page that you're a part of (assuming you're a part of one).

Granted, our ad serving process isn't entirely random, but those are the raw figures. So while being part of a company *technically* means you *might* end up on the front page of SO, the amount of times that actually happens is much, much smaller than that statement implies.

Let me re-iterate that I'm not trying to absolve us of responsibility here, I'm trying to give some perspective. As I mentioned above, we are working on fixing the copy of the invitation email to avoid things like this in the future.

Comment: Let me remind you about your comment. Four years ago this type of ad did not exist so of course no one complained!

Comment: I also can understand you will edit the email which is a very simple fix but i still don't like the fact that the ad has to show this info. If i am interested in the company Ill click on it and go to the company page.  Yes the disclaimer tells you this once you edit it but it just feels wrong.

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm proud of the company I work for and would be honored to see my profile attached to an ad. I don't think that @JonH's "feels" are universally representative. I have to agree with ross on this... if you don't want the internet to know you work for a company, you shouldn't be sharing that information in the first place... SO certainly isn't forcing you to.

Comment: No they dont force you but they also dont tell you that youll be on an ad.

Comment: @rossipedia - revoking permissions on the developer story edit profile does not work: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342898/revoking-permissions-on-company-pages-does-nothing-to-who-youll-work-with

Comment: That's a bug then. We'll get it fixed.

Comment: @JonH, they don't tell you you'll be on an ad, correct, but _isn't that the whole point of this answer_? The whole point of the answer is "Yes, you should be told what it means, but no, showing workers on ads is not a bad idea."

Answer (score 4):

The basic claim that you will be working with the people is bogus and should be removed. If the company is tiny it will be true. But in a most companies you will probably be in a different team or department.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but this answer doesn't appear to address the question.  Shouldn't it be a question itself?

Comment: It would be easier to get relevant discussion on it if it was.