# Revoking permissions on company pages does nothing to "who you'll work with"

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

I posted this yesterday:

[We need to warn "people you'll work with" that their pics, names, and location are used on public ads](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342852/we-need-to-warn-people-youll-work-with-that-their-pics-names-and-location-a)

According to user [rossipedia](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/115049/rossipedia) he states:

> Also, you can revoke your membership to any company page that you have
>   joined from your Developer Story preferences (it's under Edit Profile
>   and Settings). You don't need the owner's permission:

So I went to my developer story, went to edit profile and revoked my permissions from my company page.  I saved my changes and waited...and I still appear on my company pages "Who you'll work with".

So revoking your own permissions does not work properly.

Comment: How long did you wait?  I suspect it is highly cached.

Comment: Caching has its place - this should not be cached if it is.  I can wait more...

Comment: Thanks for your report! I'm looking into it right now and I will get back to you when I have more info about it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this.

As you deduced, this wasn't a caching issue. It was a bug. We're storing the information of the company pages in a JSON field that gets recalculated every time an employer changes the data of the company page or an employee opts-in into appearing on the company page.

What we weren't doing, was recalculating the JSON when an employee decided not to appear on the company page anymore.

I've fixed that, and the fix is already in production. Unfortunately, for the existing company pages containing people who already removed themselves from their company pages, we need the employers to update it. If you want me to refresh a particular company, feel free to leave the company page on the comments or reach me out via email (it's on my profile).

Thanks again!

Comment: Can you please refresh mine..I can always go back in and re-add myself it need be.  Wheres my SO jacket?

Comment: done! your company page has been refreshed