# How do I remove myself from "Who you'll work with" company page?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

I would like to remove myself from the Jobs page of a company I no longer work with, but I haven't found a way to do it.

Comment: So the only way it touching base with the admin of the company page?

Comment: Please see my answer here for how to remove yourself from a Company Page: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/342858/115049 for

Comment: Thanks for the support @rossipedia but I have not been able to find a way to remove myself from a company profile. I tried following the steps in that link but couldn't find the company section.

Comment: Make sure you follow the steps on stackoverflow.com, you won't be able to find that section if you do it here on meta.stackoverflow.com. If I visit that section on your profile, this is what I see (since I'm a mod/dev. normal users wouldn't see this): https://i.imgur.com/Yp4hQpb.png

Comment: Thanks @rossipedia that did the trick.